# how to add to event args of button_click

Tags: c#, windows

I have a button_click(object sender, EventArgs s) and a class Purchase:EventArgs plus a dynamically created button. I want to button to click, then send 'Purchase' instead of event args. i.e., I want to edit event args to the button as it clicks. such that I'll use that information instead, as it is a dynamically created button. how do I do that? I have several ideas such as creating a master class for the button, but I want answers.

I know it's a difficult question. but what use are event args if they are inaccessible?

```
var button = new Button();
button.Text = "change";
button.Click += button_Click;

table.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "change" }, 0, table.RowCount - 1);
            table.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Text = pr.value.ToString() }, 0, table.RowCount - 1);
            table.Controls.Add(new DateTimePicker() { Text = pr.time.ToString() }, 0, table.RowCount - 1);
            table.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Text = "transaction" }, 0, table.RowCount - 1);

            table.RowCount++;
```

I want something

```
like button.Click+=button_click(pr)
```

when

```
/*when pr:*/ Purchase pr = new Purchase()//...;
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: it's too large. I've already specified. a main

Comment: main-> FormLoad(object sender, evenArgs){
......
}

Purchase:EventArgs;

button_click; 

are the functions

Comment: @ilanGoldenberg all relevant information, especially code, needs to be put into your post itself, not into comments (which don't have proper formatting for multiple lines of code). You should [edit] your post and add that info. See: [ask]

Comment: well I already edited it. tb if I don't get an answer because I have no idea. even 'it's impossible' is ok imo.

Comment: It sounds like you want to have a common button handler function. Ie the same code triggered by each of a set of buttons, but handling a different object , is that right?

Comment: yes that right. I just want to change the event args. I tried to give each button unique names and it works though, but it's not elegant. {using btn.Name = "btn|id" then id = btn.Name.Split('|')[1]}

Comment: I bet there's a way to change the args to an event based on the name even, or whichever else. even a function to handle the event to send to the event function. either would work. I have no idea how to do that though, I could use help. I think delegate works but I don't know how to use it properly, and it'll take an hour of learning to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Set the click handler for each button to the same

Set the Tag attribute for the button to the object you want to handle in the click

```
 Button MakeButton(string text, object tag){
       var b = new Button{
         Text = text,
         Tage = tag
      };
       b.Click += button_Click;
      return b;
  }
     
 

 table.Controls.Add(MakeButton("change", new Froodle()), 0, table.RowCount - 1);
 table.Controls.Add(MakeButton(pr.value.ToString(), new Froodle()), 0, table.RowCount - 1);
```

etc

Now in the click handler pick up the object from the tag

```
 void button_Click(object sender, Eventargs e){
     var target = sender.Tag;
 }
```